# Custom Shortcode (Include, Tag) in Jekyll with Parameters and Multiline Text

Tags: jekyll

I'd like to create something like a shortcode for a blockquote in Jekyll. It should include the quote source in a nicely formatted way.

The shortcode could look like this:

```
{% quote author="My Author" %}
This is the quoted content
spanning multiple lines

And paragraphs
{% endquote %}
```

What's the best way to achieve this in Jekyll? Can it be that there is no way to provide multiple arguments to a Jekyll tag plugin?

I have found a blog post that [provides multiple attributes using string concatenation or JSON](https://blog.sverrirs.com/2016/04/custom-jekyll-tags.html).

#### My Research

I have found two systems in Jekyll that can be used similar to shortcodes:

- [HTML Includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/)
- [Custom Tags](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/tags/)

To summarize, both methods only provide a single attribute to the Ruby code, the `content`. Below, you will find the limitations of both solutions.

##### HTML Includes limiations

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/

An include in use looks like this:

```
{% include note.html content=download_note %}
```

It is possible to use content from captures for parameters, so we could create the following include file:

```
<blockquote>
    {{ include.quote | markdownify }}
    <p><em>{{ include.author }}</em></p>
</blockquote>
```

And use it in a blog post like this:

```
{% capture quote %}
This is the quote content
spanning multiple lines

And paragraphs
{% endcapture %}
{% include quote.html quote=quote author="My Author" %}
```

It works, but in my opinion, it's not really a nice approach to use when writing blog posts.

##### Custom Tags limiations

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/tags/

Sounds promising, but the documentation only shows two ways to use them:

```
{% render_time page rendered at: %}
```

and

```
{% render_time %}
page rendered at:
{% endrender_time %}
```

Comment: Edited your post. I think your research is good but your expectation is not clear. If you need more arguments for the plugin, you could write your own, no?